# How to handle multiple customers with different SQL databases

Tags: visual-studio, azure, powerbi, cube, ssas-tabular

**Summary**

I have a project with multiple existing MSSQL databases, I already created an Azure Analysis Service where I deployed my first Tabular Cube. I already tested to access the Analysis Service, worked perfectly.
Finally I have to duplicate the above described for ~90 databases (90 different customers).
I'm unsure how to organize this project and I'm not sure about the possibilities I have.

**What I did**

I already browsed the Internet to find some information, but I just found a single [source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/26f14a96-dbc9-49e8-b9a0-3ce6e3af1a58/newbie-question-multiple-tabular-models?forum=sqlanalysisservices) where somebody asked a similar question, the first reply is what I was already thinking about, as I described below.
The last reply I don't really understand, what does he mean with one solution, is there another hierarchy above the project?

**Question**

A possibility would be to import each database as a source in the same project, but I think this means I have to import each table from this source, means finally 5*90 = 450 tables, I think this gets quickly outta control?

Also I thought about duplicating the whole Visual Studio Project folder for ~90 times for each customer, but at the moment I fail to find all references to change the name, but I think this wouldn't be to hard.

Is there an easier way to achieve my goal? Especially regarding maintainability.

**Solution**

I will make a completely new Database with all the needed tables. Inside those tables I copy the databases from all customers with a new column customerId. The data I'll transfer with a cyclic job, periodicity to define. Updates in already existing row in the customer database I handle with a trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this the best approach would be to create a staging database and import the data from the other databases, so your Tabular Model can read the data from it.

Doing 90+ databases is going to be a massive admin overhead and getting the cube to lad them effectively is going to be problematic. Move the data using SSIS/Data factory as you'll be able to better orchestrate the data movement, and incremental loads that way. That way if you need to add/remove/update data sources it is not done in the Cube, its all done at the database/data factory level.

Comment: Thanks Jonee, I will make it as Yomzee and you told me.

Answer (score 0):

Just use one database for all the customers and differentiate each customer with a customer_id column.

Comment: Hi Yomzee, thanks for your quick reply. To clarify: Are you talking about merging all customer SQL tables into one big SQL table? If yes, this wouldn't be possible. Or is there a possibility to merge those tables in the tabular model, so I don't have to touch the SQL database?

Comment: I just thought a while about it, I don't know yet how to solve your suggestion, but I think I would have a problem with the size of one specific table, in there we would have around 40 mio rows with some joins in the background, I think with live queries this would take a while. Just checked the computing time of one client with 1.5 mio rows, took more than 10 secs.